# Implementing PHP Connect solution

Tags: php, docusignapi

New to the DocuSign api `SDK`. We're trying to get an `HTTP` development version with the Connect solution working. Code in `SDK` says:

```
// NOTE: DocuSign only pushes status to HTTPS!
$postBackPath = empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http://' : 'https://';
$postBackPath .= ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

Is this how we should configure for our server?

$postBackPath = empty($_SERVER['HTTP']) ? 'http://ourURL.com/listener/index.php';
$postBackPath .= ($_SERVER['ourURL.com'] . ':' . $_SERVER['80'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things here. The first comment states that Connect only pushes to HTTPS (not HTTP).

With this being said, you wouldn't be able to use port 80, you'd have to use port 443.

$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] will pull the url path being used to access the application (127.0.0.1 for localhost, or www.domain.com for a website).

Read more on [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) at php.net

Also the documentation states to not change that portion of the configuration, just copy it from the SDK into your web server.

[DocuSign SDK PHP ReadMe](https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK/tree/master/PHP/Connect)

### Sample PHP Connect solution instructions

In order to start receiving events from your DocuSign account please follow the 
configuration in the *HTTPS Connect Guide* included in the DocuSign SDK.

PHP Connect solution contains just one project. The project consists of one PHP file and 
one sample data file. The data file can be used to test out the post processing.

Just like with a lot of PHP solutions deployment of the PHP sample is as simple as just 
copying the files into a directory on your server.

The sample has been tested with the following configuration:

```
- PHP Version 5.2.6 
- cURL support: libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.7l zlib/1.2.3
```

The url that you post the index.php can be used for both sending

```
https://<your_secure_server>/<somefolder>/index.php
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Mark this as an answer if it worked for you, so other's can benefit off of it.